# "Default" parameter on every ejs render call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

To verify if a user is an admin , I'm doing the following code in **all** my ejs files

in node.js routes, I send the user as a parameter when I render ejs

```
 router.get('/', (req, res) => {
 res.render('index.ejs',{query: req.session.username});
 });
```

And in my frontend, I just do :

```
  <% if(query == 'pedrosarkis'){ %>
  <li class="nav-item admin">
    <a class="nav-link" href="/admin">Admin</a>
  </li> <% } %>
```

The "problem"(i guess it is) is that I have too many pages, which means that every route I'll have to pass the username as a parameter, is there a way to pass a parameter whenever a ejs is rendered? Like a middleware or something like  that

Answer (score 3):

It is quite simple, Use `locals` object, which according to [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals), is

> An object that contains response local variables scoped to the
>   request, and therefore available only to the view(s) rendered during
>   that request / response cycle (if any). Otherwise, this property is
>   identical to app.locals.
>
> This property is useful for exposing request-level information such as
>   the request path name, authenticated user, user settings, and so on.

So, in your main js file (app.js, server.js, whatever you name it), before your routes definition, you can use the following middleware

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.query = req.session.username;
  next();
});
```

and `query` will be accessible in every rendered ejs file

Answer (score 0):

You could write a helper function that serves as a simple abstraction. Even though adding the line `query: req.session.username,` in a couple of places shouldn't be that big of a hassle.

```
const renderEJS = (req, res, fileName, options = {}) => 
  res.render(fileName, {
    query: req.session.username,
    ...options
  });

renderEJS(req, res, 'index.ejs');
```

or

```
const prepareEJSOptions = (req, options = {}) => ({
   query: req.session.username,
   ...options
});

const options = prepareEJSOptions(req);
res.render('index.ejs', options);
```